# Use of SystemLocale method of NSLocale class

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, foundation

I really don't understand what is the use of instance object made by `systemLocale` method, while it is nil all the time.

Can you please describe that with a practical example?

Comment: What platform?  What version of that platform?

Comment: in Xcode for both OSX and IOS

Answer (score 0):

You may use SystemLocat to get currency formate, number formate or many other things.
here is the example

```
 NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale systemLocale];
    [currencyFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormat setLocale:locale];       
    NSLog(@"Current currencyCode : %@", [currencyFormat currencyCode]);
```

Comment: as I said before when I run above code , what I get is just (null) , unless I use 'CurrentLocale' instead of 'SystemLocale' method

Comment: use device instead simulator